# Sending Cookie cross-domain with CORS using jQuery, hosted with MVC. Troubleshooting checklist?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, cookies, cross-domain

Looking for some help, I've checked just about everything online and I can't figure out why it's not working for me. I'm working on a very stripped down proof-of-concept but I'm thinking it should work, but I suspect I am missing something obvious and am just not smart enough to see it. **I've changed http to hxxp because Stack Exchange won't let me post this question otherwise.**

Browser is connecting to Domain 1. A page is getting served with MVC. This original response comes with the following headers. **Please note the Set-Cookie line:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: Original=Chocolate; path=/
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?YzpcdXNlcnNcZWNhbXBvc1xkb2N1bWVudHNcdmlzdWFsIHN0dWRpbyAyMDE1XFByb2plY3RzXENvb2tpZVRyYWRlQVxDb29raWVUcmFkZUE=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Origin: http://orghost:54605
Date: Tue, 02 May 2017 21:08:19 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

The page being served has a single button and I have jQuery code to dispatch an Ajax GET. The script looks like the following:

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnCORS').click(function () {
        $.support.cors = true;

        var request = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'hxxp://duplihost:54614/Ajax/Ping',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'json',
            crossDomain: true,
            xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
            success: function (response) {
                alert('Success');
            },
            error: function(xhr, status) {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

When I click the button, I notice traffic in Fiddler. First the preflight:

Request

```
OPTIONS hxxp://duplihost:54614/Ajax/Ping HTTP/1.1
Host: duplihost:54614
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: hxxp://orghost:54605
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: hxxp://orghost:54605/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Allow: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Public: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?YzpcdXNlcnNcZWNhbXBvc1xkb2N1bWVudHNcdmlzdWFsIHN0dWRpbyAyMDE1XFByb2plY3RzXENvb2tpZVRyYWRlQlxDb29raWVUcmFkZUJcQWpheFxQaW5n?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: hxxp://orghost:54605
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, *
Date: Tue, 02 May 2017 20:59:52 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Then the actual call. **Please notice there is no "cookie" line here which was expected.**

Request:

```
GET hxxp://duplihost:54614/Ajax/Ping HTTP/1.1
Host: duplihost:54614
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: hxxp://orghost:54605
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: hxxp://orghost:54605/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?YzpcdXNlcnNcZWNhbXBvc1xkb2N1bWVudHNcdmlzdWFsIHN0dWRpbyAyMDE1XFByb2plY3RzXENvb2tpZVRyYWRlQlxDb29raWVUcmFkZUJcQWpheFxQaW5n?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: hxxp://orghost:54605
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, *
Date: Tue, 02 May 2017 20:59:54 GMT
Content-Length: 15
```

I've been working at this for several days and everything I find online seems to take me in circles and winds up verifying the same stuff that I know for sure are being done. I know for sure I have my CORS headers set up. I know for sure I am using "withCredentials" in the ajax call.

Ultimately, I want the Ping handler in the Ajax controller of duplihost to be able to see that there is a orghost cookie named Original and it's set to Chocolate. I'd very much appreciate any help.

Comment: Which browsers are you testing in? Do you see the same behavior in all browsers? Are third-party cookies disabled in whatever browser(s) you’re testing with?

Comment: So far, Chrome, Firefox, and IE 11 all seem to not work. None of them have 3rd party cookies disabled. [This page](https://alanhogan.github.io/web-experiments/3rd/third-party-cookies.html) tells me they're working properly.